# Convert string that is not a number to integer

Tags: excel, vba, string, type-conversion, integer

I need to convert a string into a numerical value.

My string is not a number. I define the numerical value of this string in my program.

This is the test I am performing:

[image]

```
Sub TestFinal()

    Dim Result As Integer

    Dim StartNumber As Integer
    Dim EndNumber As Integer

    Dim b As Variant
    Dim d As Variant

    Dim ValCellY As String
    Dim ValCellZ As String

    StartNumber = 2   'First line value of my table
    EndNumber = 3     'Last line value of my table

    b = 80
    d = 20

    For StartNumber = 2 To EndNumber   'Begining of my loops

        ValCellY = Cells(StartNumber, 2).Value
        ValCellZ = Cells(StartNumber, 3).Value

        If Cells(StartNumber, 1) = "Yes" Then  'First if condition
            Result = 100
        End If

        If Cells(StartNumber, 1) = "No" Then    'Second if condition
            'I use CInt function to convert my string into a integer
            Result = 75 * CInt(ValCellY) + 25 * CInt(ValCellZ)  
        End If

        'I associate the varaible Result to the column D
        Cells(StartNumber, 4).Value = Result

    Next StartNumber    'End of my loops

End Sub
```

I don't understand why the value **b** and **d** are not taken into account.
Moreover a message error: "type mismatch" appears.

Comment: You are trying to do calculations on the letter "b".

Answer (score 0):

Convert them back to the variables.

```
    ValCellY = IIf(Cells(StartNumber, 2).Value = "b", b, d)
    ValCellZ = IIf(Cells(StartNumber, 3).Value = "b", b, d)
```

Comment: Hello,
I am not sure to understand the purpose of this. Can you explain me?
Thanks

Comment: It makes ValCellY & ValCellZ equal to the variables in your code, did you not try it?

Comment: You need to click this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using strings to calculate instead of actual values. You might use if, or select case but if your actual problem is more complex then I suggest using dictionary.

```
  Option Explicit

    Sub TestFinal()

        Dim Result As Integer

        Dim StartNumber As Integer
        Dim EndNumber As Integer

        Dim b As Variant
        Dim d As Variant

        Dim ValCellY As String
        Dim ValCellZ As String

        StartNumber = 2   'First line value of my table
        EndNumber = 3     'Last line value of my table

        b = 80
        d = 20


        For StartNumber = 2 To EndNumber   'Begining of my loops

            ValCellY = Cells(StartNumber, 2).Value
            ValCellZ = Cells(StartNumber, 3).Value

            If Cells(StartNumber, 1) = "Yes" Then  'First if condition
                Result = 100
            End If

            If Cells(StartNumber, 1) = "No" Then    'Second if condition

                If ValCellY = "b" Then
                    ValCellY = b
                ElseIf ValCellY = "d" Then
                    ValCellY = d
                End If

                If ValCellZ = "b" Then
                    ValCellZ = b
                ElseIf ValCellZ = "d" Then
                    ValCellZ = d
                End If

                Result = 75 * CInt(ValCellY) + 25 * CInt(ValCellZ)  'I use CInt function to convert my string into a integer

            End If

            Cells(StartNumber, 4).Value = Result  'I associate the varaible Result to the column D

        Next StartNumber    'End of my loops

    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain me what do you mean by dictionary?

Comment: A dictionary stores unique keys and values assigned to keys. You can create dictionary and later refer to it by the key. Here is a nice article about dictionaries in VBA: https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/ If my reply was helpful please approve the answer :)